# The text of TextView disappears (not wrapped) despite the TextView taking its appropriate size

Tags: java, android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I'm using ConstraintLayout (still a beginner). The text of the textviews just won't appear.

snippet of xml:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/goldenrod"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="-8.7sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="26.7sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:text="JOIN US" />
```

I tried both:

```
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

Edit:
I also tried to make the textview "wrap_content" and "match_parent"

Edit 2:
My mistake after all. Was using namespace "tools" instead of "android"

Comment: When you say "won't appear" what exactly do you mean? `tools:text` will just set the text in the designer view and not at run time. Are you setting the text at runtime? Post your full XML for a better look.

Comment: I can't believe i made such a stupid mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Mark the question as answered or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You must change this param:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Try :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Or a value greater than 0dp.